# How to clean the cache programmatically when uninstalling an app?

Tags: android, caching

I have a chat app , unread messages of chat are described as a unread above the logo of application as a given in pic(picture is just for sample) , THE PROBLEM is that when I delete the app and reinstall it , the previous unread message counter again set for new install even if I don't log in my account in app. Is it possible to clean the cache automatically when uninstall my application. My code for setting unread message to the logo:

[image]

```
                    if (unread_message > 0)
                        ShortcutBadger.applyCount(CasesActivity.this, unread_message);
                    else
                        ShortcutBadger.removeCount(CasesActivity.this);
```

Comment: Everything is cleaned when you uninstall the app.  You might be running into cloud backup.  But there is no hook to run code when being uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - put android:allowBackup="false" and android:fullBackupContent="false" in  tag of manifest.xml

So -

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false">
```